# Unity3D: iTween oncomplete not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, itween

I am working on a Unity2 game, and I want to make Boom disappear in the end of `iTween` animation.

Here is part of code

```
void OnMouseDown() {    

    if (ChosePosition == false)
        ChosePosition = true;

    // make Star stop
    else if (ChosePosition == true && ChoseForce == false) {
        ChoseForce = true;
        //Compute Force power 
        PowerDegree = Mathf.Abs (Star.transform.position.y - StarPosition)/ Mathf.Abs(StarendPosition - StarPosition) * 100;

        //print (PowerDegree);

        Vector3 NewBoomPostion = new Vector3 (Luncher.transform.position.x, BoomPosition, 85);

        GameObject newBoom = Instantiate(Boom, NewBoomPostion , Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        iTween.MoveTo (newBoom, iTween.Hash 
            ("y",BoomPosition+((BoomendPosition-BoomPosition)/100*PowerDegree),
            "speed",Boomspeed,
            "EaseType",BoomeaseType,
            "LoopType",BoomloopType,
            "oncomplete","BoomComplete"
            ));


        CarrierReset = true;
        ChosePosition  = false;
        ChoseForce = false;

        //After Shot, Luncher will move
        iTween.Resume(Luncher);

        //After Shot, Luncher Carrier will display
        displayCarrierOrNot = true;
    }
}


void BoomComplete(){
    print("complete");
}
```

But I can't see "complete" in console.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I put parameters in multiple line. If I get rid of those quotes, it will throw invalid argument error.

Comment: I was wrong about trying to pass the method itself--the capitalized local variable/field names confused me into thinking you were already doing that with other methods. But I found a new answer that I'm fairly sure should help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/45782/itween-oncomplete-not-firing.html) on Unity Answers describes why you have the problem:

> By default iTween attempts to call the callback methods you provide it on the object it is animating - in your case the `mainCamera.gameObject`. Since "`onCameraShakeComplete`" does not reside on that object it is never getting called. You have two options: Move that method onto your `mainCamera.gameObject` or simply provide am "`onCompleteTarget`" of `gameObject` to tell iTween to use the GameObject that is setting up this iTween.

In your case the object it is animating is `newBoom`, but you have the callback on your own component. To make iTween use your current callback you can add a parameter to your `Hash` call:

```
iTween.MoveTo (newBoom, iTween.Hash(
    // ...
    "oncomplete", "BoomComplete",
    "oncompletetarget", gameObject
    ));
```

Comment: This helped me today, thanks 6 years later!